# Search Results Within System Preferences Not Highlighted

Tags: macos, system-settings, ui

This is just a minor annoyance, but usually, when typing in the search field inside of System Preferences, the icons for matching search results receive kind of a glowing background or highlight. Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, this doesn't happen on only one of my macs (early 2009 iMac). Has anyone else experienced this or know if there's a way to fix it?

Comment: Have you got **System Preferences** checked on the Spotlight Preferences under, well, System Preferences? Or have you got any excluded files?

Comment: I do. I'm not sure if it's Spotlight related. Functionally, it works fine---the correct results are provided in the autocompleted dropdown, but, visually, the "glow" just isn't there as it was before.

Comment: Which files have you got excluded?